# dll for voice recognition through kinect needed for c++ project

Tags: c++, dll, kinect, speech-recognition

i am new to kinect development, I have watched the sample project for speech recognition with name "SpeechBasics-D2D" given in kinect sdk. it works fantastic. I need this whole project as class library (like .dll file). I have removed "TurtleController" class from project and all its refrences. (still worked fine). then I removed GUI part and try to initiate the class "SpeechBasics" from my main project, it does not start listening through kinect. I just convert the sample project "SpeechBasics-D2D" to  class library project and try to call it from my main project. kindly give me some suggessions as i am stuck at this point, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Kinect demo applications are using the Microsoft Speech Platform SDK; Version 11 being the latest.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

In the C++ example I'd look through the "CSpeechBasics::CreateFirstConnected()" function.  This is the function that finds the Kinect sensor and links it to the Speech SDK.  The additional function calls made from it are all related to that.

Take note of what calls are being made into the references created here.  Those are how the rest of the program are linking into the Speech SDK (the Kinect only serves as a microphone), and thus are what you will want to expose with your DLL.

Also - I'd recommend adding the "speech-recognition" and possibly the "speechrecognitionengine" tag to this post.  That may capture a few more people who have tackled this.